# Union of protocols with invariant generic type causes problems

Tags: python, generics, typeerror, mypy

I have a protocol `MyExporter` using a generic type `T`:

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseSample)

class MyExporter(Protocol[T]):
    def get_sample(self) -> T:
        ...

    def process_sample(self, sample: T) -> str:
        ...
```

I also have a function that, given a string, will return a module implementing `MyExporter` with `T` set to one of two possible `BaseSample` subclasses, `SampleA` or `SampleB`:

```py
def get_exporter(name: str) -> Union[MyExporter[SampleA], MyExporter[SampleB]]:
    if name == "a":
        return my_exporter_a
    return my_exporter_b
```

My problem is when I use `MyExporter` like this:

```py
exporter = get_exporter("a")
sample = exporter.get_sample()
output = exporter.process_sample(sample) # type checker complains here
```

I get the following errors from mypy:

```
Argument 1 to "process_sample" of "MyExporter" has incompatible type "Union[SampleA, SampleB]"; expected "SampleA"
Argument 1 to "process_sample" of "MyExporter" has incompatible type "Union[SampleA, SampleB]"; expected "SampleB"
```

It makes sense that `sample` is of type `SampleA | SampleB`, but I also feel like the type checker should be able to infer that the output of `get_sample` is a valid argument to `process_sample` when using the same exporter.

Is there any way around this that doesn't require an architectural overhaul?

Comment: Based on your current implementation, `def get_exporter(name: str) -> MyExporter[Union[SampleA, SampleB]]` would serve better. You'll have to work out the typing in the internals of `get_exporter`.

Comment: There is no way `T` can escape the `exporter` instance. When you do `exporter.get_sample()`, it does not return some magical T, but resolves it to some concrete type. It does not allow passing it to something within `exporter` that expects T, unless the bounds are satisfied. Is this example representative? If yes, you can just use `overload` to declare narrow return type: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=77e179ab5d9939f508d87ec745298864 In future, please add an MRE (R is for **Reproducible**), we shouldn't be typing all the boilerplate for you.